# What do you name a SharePoint file when the metadata takes cares of all the naming for you?

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

I am tyring to implement effective metadata to my SharePoint libraries. Great I think! No longer have to put the relevant meeting date at the start of every document name, you can make it a tag! make document purpose a tag (presentation, minutes etc), make a committee name tag. All this worked wonderfully until it came time to name the actual files. What name do you give to a document when all the relative information has been defined via tags? Anything I think of just seems like an information duplication... plus the names need to be unique...

Any thoughts on what anyone else has done to counter this problem would be great =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What *exactly* is wrong with just "Meeting notes March 2010"?
I realise that you may have already tagged the file "Meeting", but you have to call the file *something*, so why not call it what it actually is?

Besides, if I download that file and it has the name "File 002737", that's going to look pretty meaningless when I look at it in a couple of days"

Comment: Definitely agree that the filename should mean something to the user if they download it.